# Spring Boot complex Query

Tags: spring-boot, repository

I am trying to create a method in the repository to be able to find out what is the most recent contract signed by an employee. The problem I have is that if I want to filter by the start date of the contract, I also have to pass it as a parameter and I don't have that, that's what I need. I tried this but the result is all contracts of this employee.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * "
    + "FROM Contracts c "
    + "WHERE c.employeeName = :name "
    + "AND c.dateStartContract = ("
        + "SELECT MAX(dateStartContract) "
        + "FROM Contracts d "
        + "WHERE d.employeeName = :name)")
public Contract findByContractIDEmployeeName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Do you want to obtain the most recent contract for a specific employee..? Because if you want that then you have to (in SQL I specify) make an `order by DESC` on the date of the contract with a `limit 0.1`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying this. Concretly I tried this too `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Contracts c WHERE c.employeeName = :name AND c.dateStartContract = (SELECT MAX(dateStartContract) from Contracts d where d.employeeName = :name)") public Contract findByContractIDEmployeeNameAndByTop1ByContractIDDateStartContract(@Param("name") String name);`. But it tells me that Contract does not have an element called byContractIDDateStartContract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the import of `@Query` at the repository was `import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;` and must be `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;`.
After this change, the consult to data base is exactly my Query request.

My query is this.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT c "
    + "FROM Contract c "
    + "WHERE c.contractID.employeeName = :name "
    + "AND c.contractID.contractStartDate = ("
        + "SELECT MAX(contractID.contractStartDate) "
        + "FROM Contract d "
        + "WHERE d.contractID.employeename = :name)")
public Contract findByContractIDNameEmployeeAndByContractIDDateStartContract(@Param("name") String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to do a query to find all and sort it using descending order:

```
List<Contract> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
```

Then you can just pick the first item of the list and that will represent the most recent contract signed.

You can also append so you can find by a specific name only:

```
List<Contract> findAllByOrderByIdDescAndName(String name);
```

It might be some slight error in my code since I have not had the opportunity to test it.

Comment: I would need to have the result only with the query to the database, without the need for the application to filter it later, anyway, I have tried the last option, because it would simply have to take the first item in the list, but it tells me that it can't find any Contract attribute named "and" or named "andContractID...". I have tried these two things: `public List<Contract> findAllByContractIDEmployeeNameAndOrderByContractIDDateStartContractDesc(String name);` and `public List<Contract> findAllByOrderByContractIDDateStartContractDescAndContractIDEmployeeName(String name)`